# disableing image submit button doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Just wondering if there was a difference between disabling a submit button and image submit button(input type="image") in Jquery.

Thanks

Comment: link help :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237896/how-to-disable-submit-button-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Not really, both would be disabled the same way:

```
$('#someId').attr('disabled',true);
```

Comment: Mr liddle will be coming for your blood Karim :) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237896/how-to-disable-submit-button-with-jquery/1237908#1237908

Comment: @redsquare - who the heck is Mr Liddle?

Comment: the guy who marked me down for the same answer as yours in that post