# jQuery disable/enable submit button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="textField" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
```

How can I do something like this:

- When the text field is empty the submit should be disabled (disabled="disabled").
- When something is typed in the text field to remove the disabled attribute.
- If the text field becomes empty again(the text is deleted) the submit button should be disabled again.

I tried something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('input[type="text"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).val != ''){
            $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

…but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use removeAttr('disabled') like this. Use prop() to toggle the state. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26035133/664132) or [the official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: ...and docs for [`.prop( "disabled", false )`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value)

Answer (score 1424, accepted):

The problem is that the change event fires only when focus is moved away from the input (e.g. someone clicks off the input or tabs out of it).  Try using keyup instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
     $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
           $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
     });
 });
```

Comment: The prop('disabled', true) method should be used over the attr('disabled','disabled') method [see the docs on prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 171):

```
$(function() {
  $(":text").keypress(check_submit).each(function() {
    check_submit();
  });
});

function check_submit() {
  if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
    $(":submit").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 108):

This question is 2 years old but it's still a good question and it was the first Google result, but all of the existing answers recommend setting and **removing** the HTML **attribute** (`removeAttr("disabled")`) "disabled", which is not the right approach. There is a lot of confusion regarding attribute vs. property.

### HTML

The "disabled" in `<input type="button" disabled>` in the markup [is called a *boolean attribute* by the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-disabled).

### HTML vs. DOM

Quote:

> A property is in the DOM; an attribute is in the HTML that is parsed into the DOM.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572855/664132

### jQuery

Related:

> Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The **attribute** actually corresponds to the `defaultChecked` property and **should be used only to set the initial value** of the checkbox. The checked attribute value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the checked property does. Therefore, the cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to use the property.

Relevant:

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the **disabled property** of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. **The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method.**

```
$( "input" ).prop( "disabled", false );
```

---

## Summary

**To [...] change DOM properties such as the [...] disabled state of form elements, use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.**

(http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

As for the disable on change part of the question: There is an event called "input", but [browser support is limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) and it's not a jQuery event, so jQuery won't make it work. The change event works reliably, but is fired when the element loses focus. So one might combine the two (some people also listen for `keyup` and paste).

Here's an untested piece of code to show what I mean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $submit = $('input[type="submit"]');
    $submit.prop('disabled', true);
    $('input[type="text"]').on('input change', function() { //'input change keyup paste'
        $submit.prop('disabled', !$(this).val().length);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 63):

To remove disabled attribute use,

```
 $("#elementID").removeAttr('disabled');
```

and to add disabled attribute use,

```
$("#elementID").prop("disabled", true);
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 45):

or for us that dont like to use jQ for every little thing:

```
document.getElementById("submitButtonId").disabled = true;
```

Comment: This answer getting 25 upvotes explains much crappy code there's around the world :/

Answer (score 31):

eric, your code did not seem to work for me when the user enters text then deletes all the text. i created another version if anyone experienced the same problem. here ya go folks:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
    if($('input[type="text"]').val() == ""){
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else{
        $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 23):

It will work like this:

```
$('input[type="email"]').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $(':button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $(':button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Make sure there is an 'disabled' attribute in your HTML

Answer (score 16):

We can simply have if & else .if suppose your input is empty we can have

```
if($(#name).val() != '') {
   $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false);
}
```

else we can change false into true

Answer (score 15):

you can also use something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
    $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup',function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false);
        }else{
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , true);
        }
    });
});
```

here  is [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/JRVyN/)

Answer (score 14):

**For form login:**

```
<form method="post" action="/login">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="35" maxlength="40" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="15" maxlength="20" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send">
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#send').prop('disabled', true);

    $('#email, #password').keyup(function(){

        if ($('#password').val() != '' && $('#email').val() != '')
        {
            $('#send').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#send').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's the solution for **file input field**.

To disable a submit button for file field when a file is not chosen, then enable after the user chooses a file to upload:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitButtonId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#fileFieldId").change(function(){
        $("#submitButtonId").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<%= form_tag your_method_path, :multipart => true do %><%= file_field_tag :file, :accept => "text/csv", :id => "fileFieldId" %><%= submit_tag "Upload", :id => "submitButtonId" %><% end %>
```

Answer (score 10):

If the button is itself a jQuery styled button (with .button()) you will need to refresh the state of the button so that the correct classes are added / removed once you have removed/added the disabled attribute.

```
$( ".selector" ).button( "refresh" );
```

Answer (score 9):

The answers above don't address also checking for menu based cut/paste events.  Below's the code that I use to do both.  Note the action actually happens with a timeout because the cut and past events actually fire before the change happened, so timeout gives a little time for that to happen.

```
$( ".your-input-item" ).bind('keyup cut paste',function() {
    var ctl = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.your-submit-button').prop( 'disabled', $(ctl).val() == '');
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Disable: `$('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);`

Enable: `$('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');`

The above enable code is more accurate than:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

You can use both methods.

Answer (score 7):

Vanilla JS Solution. It works for a whole form not only one input.

In question selected JavaScript tag.

HTML Form:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form')
    var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input')
    var required_inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[required]')
    var register = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]')
    form.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        var disabled = false
        inputs.forEach(function(input, index) {
            if (input.value === '' || !input.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
                disabled = true
            }
        })
        if (disabled) {
            register.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
        } else {
            register.removeAttribute('disabled')
        }
    })
```

```html
<form action="/signup">
        <div>
            <label for="username">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" required/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="r_password">Retype Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="r_password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Signup" disabled="disabled" />
    </form>
```

Some explanation:

In this code we add keyup event on html form and on every keypress check all input fields. If at least one input field we have are empty or contains only space characters then we assign the true value to disabled variable and disable submit button.

If you need to disable submit button until all required input fields are filled in - replace:

```
inputs.forEach(function(input, index) {
```

with:

```
required_inputs.forEach(function(input, index) {
```

where required_inputs is already declared array containing only required input fields.

Answer (score 3):

I had to work a bit to make this fit my use case.

I have a form where all fields must have a value before submitting.

Here's what I did:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#form_id button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);

       $('#form_id input, #form_id select').keyup(function() {
          var disable = false;

          $('#form_id input, #form_id select').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() == '') { disable = true };
          });

          $('#form_id button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', disable);
       });
  });
```

Thanks to everyone for their answers here.

Answer (score 3):

**Please see the below code to enable or disable Submit button**

> If Name and City fields has value then only Submit button will be enabled.

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);

    $('#Name').keyup(function() {
      ToggleButton();
    });
    $('#City').keyup(function() {
      ToggleButton();
    });

  });

function ToggleButton() {
  if (($('#Name').val() != '') && ($('#City').val() != '')) {
    $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
    return true;
  } else {
    $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    return false;
  }
} </script>
```

```html
<form method="post">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Getting started</h2>
      <fieldset>
        <label class="control-label text-danger">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" class="form-control" />
        <label class="control-label">Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="Address" name="Address" class="form-control" />
        <label class="control-label text-danger">City</label>
        <input type="text" id="City" name="City" class="form-control" />
        <label class="control-label">Pin</label>
        <input type="text" id="Pin" name="Pin" class="form-control" />
        <input type="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-success" />
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

take look at this snippet from my project

```
 $("input[type="submit"]", "#letter-form").on("click",
        function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();


$.post($("#letter-form").attr('action'), $("#letter-form").serialize(),
                 function(response) {// your response from form submit
                    if (response.result === 'Redirect') {
                        window.location = response.url;
                    } else {
                        Message(response.saveChangesResult, response.operation, response.data);
                    }
});
$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //this is what you want
```

> so just disabled the button after your operation executed

`$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Answer (score 1):

Al types of solution are supplied. So I want to try for a different solution. Simply it will be more easy if you add a `id` attribute in your input fields.

```
<input type="text" name="textField" id="textField"/>
<input type="submit" value="send" id="submitYesNo"/>
```

Now here is your `jQuery`

```
$("#textField").change(function(){
  if($("#textField").val()=="")
    $("#submitYesNo").prop('disabled', true)
  else
    $("#submitYesNo").prop('disabled', false)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
let check = inp=> inp.nextElementSibling.disabled = !inp.value;
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textField" oninput="check(this)"/>
<input type="submit" value="send" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope below code will help someone ..!!! :)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);

    jQuery("input[name=textField]").focusin(function(){
        jQuery("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', false);
    });

    jQuery("input[name=textField]").focusout(function(){
        var checkvalue = jQuery(this).val();
        if(checkvalue!=""){
            jQuery("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else{
            jQuery("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });

}); /*DOC END*/
```

Answer (score 0):

be careful if the button was anchor tag and you are trying to make it disable

(anchor) element doesn't have a disabled property like a  does. The disabled attribute is not applicable to anchor elements.