# jQuery: removeAttr("disabled") not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that looks like the following coming back from an XHR response:

```
jQuery(':text:not(:hidden)').removeAttr("disabled");
```

This is a result of input fields being disabled after form submit. The XHR response returns this tidbit of jQuery and re-enables controls. Works great on every browser, even "partially" on FF 3.6.1 OSX. What I mean by partially is that some text fields have the disabled attribute removed, others do not. These text fields are verified not hidden.

Comment: You should really use jQuery('input:text:not(:hidden)'), it's much quicker according to the jQuery docs. As for your problem, I don't see why it shouldn't work in principle, but right now I don't have FF 3.6.1 to try it.

Comment: For changing the dynamic state, prop() should be used instead of attr()/removeAttr(), see [my answer on disabling buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26035133/664132).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a go using this instead:

```
jQuery('input:text:visible').each(function(){
    this.disabled = false;
});
```

This uses the `disabled` property of the element directly, rather than messing around with jQuery wrappers.

Comment: Go you. Not that I don't have this problem, but jquery has helped a lot of people forget how to write native javascript.

Comment: Finally, sanity. jQuery has a lot to answer for, not least the near universal confusion amongst jQuery users about the difference between attributes and properties.

Comment: Had this issue in IE (.removeAttr("disabled"); worked on FF).
This 'this.disabled' worked well for both browsers :-)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try something like:

```
jQuery('input[type=text]:visible').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead try:

```
jQuery(':text:not(:hidden)').attr("disabled",'');
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the cleanest solution, since in HTML5 the disabled (and other similar) attribute can have any value (even an empty string) and still be valid (`<input type="text" disabled />`, `<input type="text" disabled="" />` will both be disabled)

Comment: This just ended up disabling all of my text input controls.