# Why isn't jquery detecting when a radio button is unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery $(#radioButton).change(…) not firing during de-selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176803/jquery-radiobutton-change-not-firing-during-de-selection)

I have the following HTML/jQuery:

```
<input id="rb1" type="radio" name="rb" checked="true">
<input id="rb2" type="radio" name="rb">


$("#rb2").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
         alert('checked');
    }
    else {
        alert('unchecked');
    }
});
```

When my `rb2` radio button is unselected by selecting rb1, the change event does not fire.  Why is this?  Is it possible to get this working without changing my selector to match both inputs and then looking at the ID?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4uRWR/

Comment: 'cause change events only fire for radios being checked?

Comment: Seems odd that it wouldn't care about unselecting.  I mean... that's a change isn't it?

Comment: Not in the W3C spec as far as I'm aware. I'll dig it up in a bit.

Comment: It is easy to workaround though if you simply query all radios with the same name and trigger the change event on them manually.

Comment: The answer and a solution can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176803/jquery-radiobutton-change-not-firing-during-de-selection

Comment: Use a class on the group, not an ID.

Comment: Radio options are displayed in groups and so it is assumed that you bind handler to the group and not single element. The change is triggered only after the element gains the focus.. in case of uncheck, the element never gains focus. A bug report associated with this behavior https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=363693

Comment: you could just change `change` to click, therefore it will fire every time you click on the radio button, and then you can check if it is checked or not...

Comment: @ryanc1256 But he isn't clicking on rb2, he's clicking on rb1

Comment: You'll have to associate a change handler to all radios by using a name/class selector, so this is basically a duplicate of @ohaleck's linked post.

Comment: Ok, voting to close then.

Comment: @KevinB oh, i didn't really read the question in vast detail, I just skim read it.. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: You asked for a reason for why it doesn't happen though, guess I'll try to put up an answer for that as no one addressed the reason directly.

Comment: Oh never mind, @AlienHoboken did address it. But to extend it a little further, see [ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange): "The `onchange` event occurs when a control loses the input focus *and* its value has been modified since gaining focus." - as the input loses its `checked` state without gaining focus, a change event is not fired. This is the standard behavior for input of type text, I'm not sure whether this is the same for radios but it is how browsers implemented it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The change event only gets sent when you actually modify the item itself. When you click the other radio, you aren't modifying it. A fix would be to watch the change event on every input:radio, then just check the state of the relevant radio button:

```
$("input:radio").change(function () {
if ($("#rb2").is(":checked")) {
             alert('checked');
    }
    else {
        alert('unchecked');
    }
});
```

http://codepen.io/AlienHoboken/pen/akwjB

Comment: *"Is it possible to get this working without changing my selector to match both inputs and then looking at the ID"*

Comment: @KevinB: [voila](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14349004/1081234)

Answer (score 7):

Listen for change on every input related to your group of radios and then check if a specific one is selected.

```
$("input[name=rb]").change(function () {
    if ($('#rb2').is(":checked")) {
        alert('checked');
    } else {
        alert('unchecked');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4uRWR/2/

Comment: *"Is it possible to get this working without changing my selector to match both inputs and then looking at the ID"*

Comment: This gets pretty unwieldy when you have 10 radio buttons, and even more so when the number of buttons is dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

You can artificially trigger a "change" on radio buttons from the same group so that the original bound handler would get picked up and output "unchecked". The trick is to avoid being stuck in an infinite loop by recursively re-triggering the event, we can avoid that by ignoring artificial events that lack the `originalEvent` property:

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function (e) {
  var $this = $(this);

  //all inputs with the same name
  var $targetInputSelector = $("input[name=" + $this.attr("name") + "]");

  //check if the handler was fired "naturally"
  //if yes, trigger the change handler "artificially" for inputs with the same name
  if (e.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent')) {
    //exclude the element that was changed "naturally"
    //from the subset of all the elements with the same name
    $targetInputSelector.not($this).triggerHandler("change");
  }
});
```

This code works when added on top of your current handler and satisfies the *without changing my selector to match both inputs and then looking at the ID* criteria ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/a73tn/24/

Answer (score 0):

I sorta ran into this issue a few days ago.  Instead of listening for an individual click on a radio button, I listen for a click on the `<ul>` I have them in and then call this function to check if one has been selected.

```
// Iterate over the radio group and determine if one of them is selected
function loopRadBtns(btnGroup)
{
    var isChecked = false;

    btnGroup.find('input[type="radio"]').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).attr('checked'))
        {
            isChecked = true;
        }
    });
    return isChecked;
}
```