# Simple show hide div with radio button jQuery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[type=radio]").change(function()
    {
        var divId = $(this).attr("id");

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("." + divId).show();
        }
        else {
            $("." + divId).hide();
        }

    });
    $("input[type=radio]").change();

});
```

divs should show/hide depending if inputs are checked/unchecked

EDIT: I should mention that using checkboxes the divs DO show and hide, but with radios they just show :(.

It works with checkboxes but not radio buttons, why is that?

http://jsfiddle.net/qarZb/1/

Comment: `$("." + divId).show();` you're selecting a class, not an id. Use `#` instead of `.`

Comment: the divs have classes that equal the radio/checkbox id

Comment: Ah, well I guess if you would've added the HTML, I would've known that.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/5176803/1577396

Comment: see the jsfiddle crush

Comment: The problem is that the currently selected radio button doesn't receive a change event when a new radio button from the group is selected. Only the newly selected radio button receives the change event.

Comment: @crush i thought that is what the problem was just didn't know what do do about it lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because radio belongs to the same name `name='same'`, so jQuery detects that it is selected.

When you fire `change` event on `radio`, jQuery finds out that 1 of radio is selected so it shows proper div. But next time, when you click another one, yet same radio input is still selected (belongs to same name group). Basically what I did, is to add class `check` to your divs to hide/show and when firing change on radio, I'm hiding them all and then showing only the proper one.

Here's updated code:

http://jsfiddle.net/qarZb/6/

Comment: What should happen when I first use checkbox and then option button

Comment: I updated code once again, this time checking for selected checkboxes too

Comment: Your solution is better..

Answer (score 0):

This is because you cannot un-check a radio button like checkboxes.

To accomplish your task you must make a few changes to your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[type=radio]").change(function()
    {
        var divId = $(this).attr("id");

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("." + divId).show();
            $("." + divId).siblings('[class^=check]').hide();

        }
        else {
            $("." + divId).hide();
        }

    });

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/writetobhuwan/qarZb/7/)