# jQuery radio button on change does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176803/jquery-radiobutton-change-not-firing-during-de-selection) and I have seen [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9tBx/).

My `Fiddle` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e5ByP/). It's a simple question. Why doesn't it work?

```
#html
<input checked="checked" id="article_format_html" name="article[format]" type="radio" value="html">Some meaningful value
<input id="article_format_text" name="article[format]" type="radio" value="text">Another Value

#js
$("input[name='article[format]']:radio").change(alert('hola'));
```

## Edit:

On popular demand I did this:

```
.change(function(){alert('hola')});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5ByP/5/).

Result: Doesn't work.

## Edit 2: (Why I had the problem)

So, JS-Fiddle wraps your js code in the head of the `iframe` that is your `Result` section. For jQuery selectors (or any js that manipulates the DOM) to work properly, it has to be executed **after** the DOM element has been rendered. Hence, wrapping your code on ready and/or just before `body` closes, is the safest way to ensure that your query selectors don't return `undefined`.

Comment: change this line `.change(alert('hola'));` to this `.change(function(){alert('hola');});`

Comment: Even some people don't know to copy

Comment: All answers say the same thing. It was a stupid mistake. Which one to accept?

Comment: @RakeshShetty: And yes, it is **not** necessary to wrap code inside `.ready`. Wrapping in body also works.

Comment: @abhitalks: I was anyways going to select any answer (they all say the same thing). There's a limit to after how many minutes you can select an answer. That's new since I've never asked a question before. His comment came before time limit.

Comment: @abhitalks did I said it is complusory ? and I am not forcing anyone to accept my answer, I said `IF` see my comment

Comment: @abhitalks: I was doing that only (" Wrapping in body"). It wasn't working. I HAD to put it onDomReady or .ready()

Comment: @manu29.d: No. That wasn't your problem. Your problem was lack of a callback or anonymous function block. If you see my fiddle, I haven't wrapped it in `.ready`. Wrapped in body. And it works.

Comment: @abhitalks lets try not to be too chatty please

Comment: @abhitalks: Saw the edit?

Comment: @manu29.d: because you wrapped it in `head` not `body` !!

Comment: my answer is wrong ?? lol

Comment: @abhitalks his answer is not wrong and op solved his problem

Comment: @abhitalks let it be now. You got what you want. Cheers :) I don't mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use a callback or anonymous function block
2. You are using jQuery 1.11 (better to use `.on` syntax)

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/e5ByP/2/***

```
$("input[name='article[format]']:radio").on("change", function() { 
    alert('hola'); 
});
```

Comment: hmmm...considering other answers, this one puzzles me.

Comment: @manu29.d: You don't have to change your choice of accepted answer. Rakesh's answer solves your problem so a change of choice wasn't required.

Comment: @abhitalks but you want your answer to be accepted so OP did that.

Comment: All the other answers wrapped the handler on ready (| onDomReady | $(fucntion()..). Yours was wrapped in body. Can you make an edit and explain why both the methods work? 
And your syntax also `$("input[name='article\\[format\\]']:radio")`

Comment: @RickSmarty: Please don't distort the discussions. I never said and never wanted to get this accepted. On the contrary, it was me who said that it was Op's prerogative.

Comment: @abhitalks there should be no discussions only you have started. Since OP has already marked the answer as accepted then why to change his mind? He marked because he tried Rakesh solution and it worked for him and this not show that your answer is wrong. So stay calm and enjoy the SO

Comment: @manu29.d This is the most unreadable format :))) If you really want to use `"` in the selector (as I do every time), use: `$('input[name="article[format]"]:radio').on();` Why to escape `"` when you can use `'` as delimiter?

Comment: @vaso123: I chuckled after seeing your comment. This question is almost 3 years old now. And this is most embarrassing thing I've posted on SO. I do use the syntax you mentioned. :) And I now realise that none of the answers explain why I had the problem. Which I understand now. :P

Comment: @manu29.d I know this feeling. Time to time I realize, how a newbee was I before X month, years. I started to develop in 1996-97, started with perl to build dynamic web pages. Until 8-9 years ago I've just used UltraEdit as a text editor, and know nothing about xDebug, IDE, used one monitor and spaghetti code  etc... Now I can not imagine how could I work like that :)))

Answer (score 3):

You code is not working because you are not wrapping your jQuery inside document.ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("input[name='article[format]']:radio").change(function()
   {
       alert('hola')
   });

});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bnp3r/)**

Answer (score 2):

The code with `.on()` should be:

```
$(document).on('change',"input[name='article[format]']:radio",function(){alert('hola')});
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/e5ByP/10/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap that in a anonymous function and DOM ready:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name='article[format]']:radio").change(function () {
        alert('hola')
    });
});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/e5ByP/6/

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have incorrect change handler syntax. also you need to wrap the code in DOM ready :

```
$("input[name='article[format]']:radio").change(function(){
  alert('hola')
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e5ByP/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

In your code you not wrap handler with [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

> handler is A function to execute each time the event is triggered.
>
> Type: Function( Event eventObject )

Try This :

```
$("input[name='article[format]']:radio").change(function(){
  alert('hola')
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/e5ByP/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use anonymous callback function in `change` event

```
$("input[name='article[format]']:radio").change(function(){
  alert('hola');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in document ready and try like this. Please see the syntax too

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name='article[format]']:radio").change(function () {
        alert('hola')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put that in side document raedy

like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[name='article[format]']:radio").change(function(){
    alert('hola')
});
});
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e5ByP/17/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

Always use DOM manipulation and events only after DOM gets fully loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name='article[format]']:radio").change(function(){alert('hola')});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the $(document).ready() and also u forgot to write function() in change()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='article[format]']:radio").change(function(){
        alert('hola')
    });
});
```

Comment: You should elaborate on your answer. Explain while this is fixing the problem.