# Add required attribute when radio is checked

Tags: javascript, required

I have a set of radiobuttons called 'price'. When the '€' radio button is selected, I want to focus on a text input field and that text input field should be required.
When I click another option, the requried attribute should be removed.

Is this possible through Javascript or jQuery?
I found a jQuery snippet here, but it doesn't seem to be working. This is what I have now:

```
<input type="radio" name="price" value="value" id="value_radio" onclick="document.getElementById('value_input').focus()" required>

<label for="value_input">&euro;</label>
<input type="text" name="price_value" id="value_input" pattern="\d+(,\d{1,2})?" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('value_radio').checked=true">

<script>
    $('#value_radio').change(function () {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#value_input').attr('required');
        } else {
            $('#value_input').removeAttr('required');
        }
    });
</script>

<input type="radio" name="price" id="free" value="free">
<label for="free">Free</label>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fhfrzn1d/

Comment: add `)` after `.is(':checked')` its a major error. than proceed forward

Comment: and use a better editor for coding

Comment: Thanks. However, it's still not working...  and I guess I should dump Sublime Text then :p

Comment: use sublime but u should use relevant js plugin for error testing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5176900/2191722), you have to monitor the change on both radio inputs. So move your javascript script after the second radio.

Also there was missing a `)`

Fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/fhfrzn1d/1/

```
$('input[name="price"]').change(function () {
    if($("#value_radio").is(':checked')) {
        $('#value_input').attr('required', true);
    } else {
        $('#value_input').removeAttr('required');
    }
});
```

Comment: also you need to change the click of your #value_input element to be something like `document.getElementById('value_radio').click();` to properly trigger the change handler.

Answer (score 2):

You have two (really three) mistakes in your code.

*First.* The syntax is invalid. You should fix the closing brace as @Hushme recommends in the comments.

*First (2).* Your usage of jsfiddle is invalid too. You should paste the code to the *JavaScript* section of the site and also enable jQuery library.

*Second.* `$('#value_input').attr('required')` is not creating an attribute; it's a *getter*. You should use the proper setter there:

```
$('#value_input').attr('required', true);
```

*Third.* The radiobutton change event is not firing when user deselects the radiobutton. So you should handle events on all the buttons:

```
$('input[name="price"]').change(function () { ... });
```

I've fixed your jsfiddle, see http://jsfiddle.net/fhfrzn1d/4/