# Add required attribute when fields are visible

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I've seen this thread already: [Add required attribute when radio is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340186/add-required-attribute-when-radio-is-checked) however, the answers do not target the ID of the specific radio button, only the name. I cannot acheive what I want using the name approach as the names need to be the same for my radio options, please see HTML to see what I mean.

The below code shows a radio button with just two options. It reveals the #ifYes div ONLY when the radio option #yesCheck is checked. It gets hidden if #noCheck is checked.

**My problem**

At the same time `#ifYes` is revealed I want to add the required attribute to the 2 inputs within `#ifYes` (`#businessname and #regnum`). `required` attribute to also be removed when `#ifYes` is hidden.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6cu3ybvh/)

**HTML**

```
<label>Are you a business or consumer?</label>
<span>Business</span><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" value="Business" name="customer[note][Business or Consumer?]" id="yesCheck" required/><br/>
<span>Consumer</span><input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" value="Consumer" name="customer[note][Business or Consumer?]" id="noCheck" /><br/>

 <div id="ifYes">
    <label for="businessname">Business name</label>
    <input id="businessname" type="text" name="customer[note][Business Name]" placeholder="Business Name" />
    <label for="regnum">Business Registration No.</label>
    <input id="regnum" type="text" name="customer[note][Business Reg No.]" placeholder="Business Registration No." />
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
function yesnoCheck() {

  if($('#yesCheck').is(':checked')) {
   $('#ifYes').addClass('yarp');
   $('#businessname').attr('required');​​​​​
  } else {
   $('#ifYes').removeClass('yarp');
   $('#businessname').removeAttr('required');​​​​​
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('#businessname').attr('required');​​​​​` *retrieves* the value of the attribute. To *set* it, you have to give a value to set: `$('#businessname').attr('required', 'required');​​​​​`

But for `required` and similar, it's better to use the reflected property instead. Reading: `x = $('#businessname').prop('required');`, writing: `$('#businessname').prop('required', true);` or `$('#businessname').prop('required', false);`.