# Polymer.js binding to input checked propery works only one time

Tags: html, polymer-1.0

I have the radio group:

```
<input type="radio" name="menubar" id="menubar_1" checked="{{a::change}}" > A <br> 
<input type="radio" name="menubar" id="menubar_2" checked="{{b::change}}" > B <br>
```

[Full example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xZJCi4tYP2oRtIT3j62F?p=preview)

I need to track the checked propery, but after I check-up the input, the variable will always be TRUE. Maybe it a bug?

Also I can't get work 'if' template.

And one more question: how to set default checked property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `change` event only fires when you check a radio button, not when you uncheck it. So always you check it, it goes to `true`, and when you uncheck it, it dosn't trigger `change` event [as you can see in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5176900/2686163)
For the same reason, the `dom-if` never disappears.

That doesn't happen with checkbox as you can check in [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zAinLm?p=preview), where binding and dom-if is working with the result of checkbox.