# jQuery Radio Button onChange Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I followed this example to capture an onChange() jQuery event for a radio button group:
[JQuery $(#radioButton).change(...) not firing during de-selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176803/jquery-radiobutton-change-not-firing-during-de-selection)

But in my case, the solution given in that example is not working. I have the following generated from my JSP:

```
<input id="object.reportEntity.reportEntityIsPrime1" name="object.reportEntity.reportEntityIsPrime" type="radio" value="Y_YES" checked="checked"/>Prime                             

<input id="object.reportEntity.reportEntityIsPrime2" name="object.reportEntity.reportEntityIsPrime" type="radio" value="N_NO"/>Not Prime
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      

    // Display Alert on Radio Change    
    $('input[name=object.reportEntity.reportEntityIsPrime]:radio').change(function () {
        alert('Radio Button clicked');
    }); 
}
```

The alert is not being diplayed. Also, there's this error:

**Syntax error, unrecognized expression "input"**

Comment: Is this a JSP error or a JS error?

Comment: JavaScript (JS) error. I suspect it's because of the dots used in the name.

Comment: Why do you have such a long id name? I tought that was c#

Comment: This is GENERATED by SpringMVC from the JSP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quote marks for your name like this:

```
 $('input[name="object.reportEntity.reportEntityIsPrime"]:radio')
```

Answer (score 5):

You should delegate the events.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

Also, you need to add `"` in your selector e.g. `[name=""]` Observe the following...

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[name="object.reportEntity.reportEntityIsPrime"]:radio', function() {
    alert('Radio Button clicked');
});
```

- side note: you are missing `);` on the end of your `ready` function

---

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/L62gjpr5/) - working demo

Also, be sure to check out the [jQuery Understanding Event Delegation docs](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Quote the name attribute in your selector string.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {      

            // Display Alert on Radio Change    
    $('input[name="object.reportEntity.reportEntityIsPrime"]:radio').change(function () {
                alert('Radio Button clicked');
            });

    }
```