# jQuery - radio button on click and not on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find a solution to an issue I have between click and change.
I need to capture the **click** event and not change. 
I'll explain the situation:

I have a radio button list with 3 items. 
Each **click** I need to clean a div. However, If i'm posting back and return to the client with an error(submit, server validation check failed), the change event is fired once again (obviously), and the div is cleaned.

Is there a way to distinguish between click and the checked state?

I hope I have made myself clear.
Edit:
Added some code:

```
$("input[name*='SelectedOwner']").on('change',
function () {
    var radioId = $(this).val();
    if (radioId === "2" || radioId === "3") {
        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#divclean :input").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#div1").show();
        $("#divclean :input").attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
$("input[name*='SelectedOwner']").on('click', function () {
   //Clean the output at each change
   $("#divclean :input").val("");
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Not obvious at all why change would fire more than once

Comment: `$("input[type='radio'").click(function(){});`

Comment: Take a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8Lq1p1g/), hope it can help you

Comment: Added code in OP.

Comment: I think you need to use localStorage to store clicked radios

Comment: I was missing the :checked on the document.ready when loading after the server validation.     RunHideOrShow($("input[name*='SelectedOwner']:checked").val());
Thanks everyone!

Comment: your server call is with ajax?? if not your page must be refreshing, so how can `checked` remain the same?

Comment: I'm using asp.net mvc, this is the ModelState check. The values persist if the model is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $('input[name="choose"]').click(function(e) {
   if ($(this).data('clicked')) {
    $('#theDiv').text('You have REclicked "'+ $(this).val() + '" value');
   }
   else {
    $('input[name="choose"]').data('clicked', false);
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
    $('#theDiv').text('First time you click "'+ $(this).val() + '" value');
   }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <div id="theDiv"></div>
  
  A
  <input type="radio" name="choose" value="a" />
  
  B
  <input type="radio" name="choose" value="b" />
  
  C
  <input type="radio" name="choose" value="c" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to bind the change event to every radio button:

```
$("#r1, #r2, #r3").change(function () { }
```

---

With jQuery is also possible:

```
if ($("#r1").is(":checked")) {}
```

---

More informations:
[JQuery $(#radioButton).change(...) not firing during de-selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176803/jquery-radiobutton-change-not-firing-during-de-selection)

---

I hope this helps...

Good Luck!