# Button disable unless both input fields have value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, event-handling

I have a form with two input fields and a submit button on my page, I would like to have the feature that the 'submit' button is **disabled** until there are values on both two input fields. That's the button will be clickable if and only if there are values input in both fields.

How to implement this with js and jQuery?

Here is my page:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method=post>
        <input type=text id='first_name'>
        <input type=text id='second_name'>
        <input type=submit value=Submit>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to have both js and jQuery solution

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution using jQuery:

HTML (note that I added a id to the submit button):

```
<form method=post>
    <input type="text" id="first_name">
    <input type="text" id="second_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(':text').keyup(function() {
    if($('#first_name').val() != "" && $('#second_name').val() != "") {
       $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
       $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);   
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nc6NW/1/

Comment: But after I filled both fields, I have to click somewhere else to enable the button, the button is not active automatically.

Comment: You're right, I just updated the solution and changed `.change(function()...` to `.keyup(function()...`. This should work now. The jsfiddle example is also updated.

Answer (score 4):

JQuery: [jQuery disable/enable submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button)

Pure JS:

Event listener version

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const form = document.getElementById('myForm');
  // this is a little overkill 
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    let name1 = form.first_name.value.trim();
    let name2 = form.second_name.value.trim();
    if (name1 === "" || name2 === "") e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  });
  form.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    let name1 = form.first_name.value.trim();
    let name2 = form.second_name.value.trim();
    document.getElementById('subbut').disabled = name1 === "" || name2 === "";
  });
});
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" />
  <input type="text" id="second_name" name "second_name" />
  <input id="subbut" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

HTML only version

```html
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"  required />
  <input type="text" id="second_name" name "second_name"  required />
  <input name="subbut" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, how about do it in pure jQuery?

Comment: @Mellon Please see updates. Your jQuery question is a duplicate

Comment: I think you forgot to give the name for submit button. It should be <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" name="subbut"> Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the `name` property for your form fields!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path.to/jquery.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { // on document load

   var fn = function() {
      var disable = true;
      $('#myForm input[type:text]').each(function() { // try to find a non-empty control
          if ($(this).val() != '') {
             disable = false;
          }
      });

      $('#myForm input[type:submit]').attr('disabled', disable);
   }

   $('#myForm input[type:text]').change(fn); // when an input is typed in
   fn(); // set initial state
});
</script>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="first_name">
        <input type="text" id="second_name">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $("#first_name, #second_name").bind("change keyup",
  function(){
     if($("#first_name").val() != "" && $("#second_name").val() != "")
        $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
     else
        $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").attr("disabled","disabled"); 
  });
});
```