# enable & disable a link depending on an event jquery

Tags: jquery, events

I have a link on the page that i would like to disable when the page loads, when the user clicks on the radio button i would like to enable the link. How would i do so.

```
<a href="go.html" id="goTo">Add</a>

<input type="radio" id="enableLink" name="selection" onclick="">
```

Comment: Refer here [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button

Answer (score 0):

```
    <span id="add_link">Add</span>

    $('#enableLink').live('click', function() {
       $('#add_link').html('<a href="go.html" id="goTo">Add</a>');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var isEnabled=false;    
    $("#goTo").click(function(e){
       if(!isEnabled)
       {
          e.preventDefault();
       }       
    });        
    $("#enableLink").click(function(){
        isEnabled=true;        
    });
});
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/HyKL9/2/