# How turn on and off a disable button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

can anyone help me how to turn on and off using a button.

[image]

current code:

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="one" disabled />
<input type="button" value="two"  />
</form>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("one").disabled = true / false`

Comment: Have a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use JavaScript. My example uses jQuery.
The other examples cited are a little more complicated, so I made this for you.

```
// find the elements
var $form = $('form');
var $buttons = $form.find('input[type=button]');

// event logic
$buttons.click(function(e) {
  $buttons.attr('disabled', false);
  $(this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Put this in the onload or DomReady handler on your page. Check out the fiddle if you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/G5e48/