# how to disable a button using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this code for accessing the attribute of the button throught the id of one of the form fields.. but it isn't working..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if (document.getElementById("idadminusername").style.color == 'red') {    

        $("#btn").attr("disabled", "true");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery disable/enable submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button)

Comment: Apart from the technical solution, disabling/enabling buttons depending on another element's css style is something a team mate might want to kill you for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
            if (document.getElementById("idadminusername").style.color == 'red') {

                $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);


            }
        }
```

Comment: it's also possible that his if statement is false, if for example the button is set to red via CSS and not directly via the style attribute.

Comment: @Paul more explaination of question needed

Answer (score 0):

To disable a for field you need to do e.g. this:

html

```
<form>
  <input id="foo"/>
  <input id="bar"/>
</form>
```

js

```
$("#foo").prop('disabled', true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vdkm7phw/