# Have submit button disabled in Contact Form 7 wordpress plugin form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to disable the submit button on a form from Contact Form 7 wordpress plugin. The submit button should be disabled from start and will become available when all required fields are filled. How can I achieve this?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: should try to use search function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The difference here is to know if all required fields are filled, not just a single input field. This might need some plugin function which I don't know but someone could knew.