# How to change visible button in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selector

Hello guys I have some code:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn make-editable" data-name="GlobalCorrelationMatrix" data-action="edit-row">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn make-approve" data-name="GlobalCorrelationMatrix" data-action="approve-row">Save</button>
        <button class="btn make-close" data-name="GlobalCorrelationMatrix" data-action="discard-row">Close</button>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="b">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn make-editable" data-name="GlobalCorrelationMatrix" data-action="edit-row">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn make-approve" data-name="GlobalCorrelationMatrix" data-action="approve-row">Save</button>
        <button class="btn make-close" data-name="GlobalCorrelationMatrix" data-action="discard-row">Close</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

When i use $("button.btn.approve").addClass("disabled"); the buttons from div a and div b are disabled. How to disabled button-approve only from div a?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery disable/enable submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to change your selector and make it more general to include your `.a` class:

```
$(".a > .btn-group > button.btn.approve").addClass("disabled");`
```

Comment: But, how i Can change visible when i click button? Some like this?

$( ".a > .btn-group > button.btn.approve" ).click(function() {
  $(" .b > .btn-group > button.btn.approve").addClass("disabled");
});

Answer (score 3):

If you click the button, you only want to add class to the buttons in the same group?

If so do this:

```js
$('.btn-group .btn').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('.btn').addClass('disabled');
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn make-editable" data-name="GlobalCorrelationMatrix" data-action="edit-row">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn make-approve" data-name="GlobalCorrelationMatrix" data-action="approve-row">Save</button>
        <button class="btn make-close" data-name="GlobalCorrelationMatrix" data-action="discard-row">Close</button>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="b">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn make-editable" data-name="GlobalCorrelationMatrix" data-action="edit-row">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn make-approve" data-name="GlobalCorrelationMatrix" data-action="approve-row">Save</button>
        <button class="btn make-close" data-name="GlobalCorrelationMatrix" data-action="discard-row">Close</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Select buttons only within the div has class `a` by updating the selector.

```
$("div.a button.btn.approve").addClass("disabled");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
 $(".a button.btn.approve").addClass("disabled");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.b>.button.btn.approve
```

You need to define exact element because

```
button.btn.approve
```

Matches all buttons, you can add additional class or ID too

Comment: This won't work as `.button` isn't a direct child of `.b`