# Toggle Icon in Form Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a login screen where I need to display the password requirements and matching status. Currently, the password requirements are working as needed, but the problem I am having is with the matching password field addon that needs to go from a gray (null and default) to a red "X" (missing or mismatching password) or green "✔" (matching passwords), just as it happens with the password requirements status.

Here's the working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/ax6egohs/58/)**

Such status must be displayed using the following tag as it is part of Bootstrap's input-group:

```
<span id="matchpswstatus" class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
```

This is part of the bootstrap group, like so:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="password" id="matchpsw" name="matchpsw" class="form-control reenterpassword" placeholder="Re-enter Password" required />
    <span id="matchpswstatus" class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help in getting the gray "✖" to turn red in case a User re-enters a mismatching password OR to turn into a green "✔" in case both passwords are a match.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, to get it to change from an X to a check you just have to swap out the `fa-times` for `fa-check`.  Then as far as the color goes that can be done with css.  Which part of that has you confused?

Comment: couldn't you disable the submit button if the passwords didn't match? (alternately perhaps?)

Comment: I like your suggestion Rachel. I've made some minor modification to the code below: http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/6av5h2dr/14/

How could we disable the submit button until there are passwords match using the jsfiddle above?  Thanks.

Comment: @MarceloMartins I only saw your reply to comment now (just because I was browsing past questions).. please use the '@' sign to tag a user in future, that way the message will go into inbox notifications. Btw, I know you resolved the css, but you could still disable the button using the disabled property. Have a look at the answers to this question (they cover this issue with both vanilla js and jquery) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same approach as with the password requirements, you could do something like this:

```
var matchpswstatus = document.getElementById("matchpswstatus");
var divCheckPasswordMatch = document.getElementById("divCheckPasswordMatch");

$(function() {
  $("#matchpsw").keyup(function() {
    if ($("#psw").val() === $(this).val()) {
        divCheckPasswordMatch.textContent = "Passwords match.";
      matchpswstatus.classList.add("match");
      matchpswstatus.classList.remove("nomatch");
      matchpswstatus.textContent = "✔";
    } else {
        divCheckPasswordMatch.textContent = "Passwords do not match!";
      matchpswstatus.classList.add("nomatch");
      matchpswstatus.classList.remove("match");
      matchpswstatus.textContent = "✖";
    }
  });
});
```

with added css:

```
.match {
  color: green;
}
.nomatch {
  color: red;
}
```

But you also might want to update when the first password input is changed.

Comment: That was awesome!  I made a bit of modification to your code, if you care to review it.  http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/6av5h2dr/14/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yep, looks like you've got it.  Happy to help.