# How to check user email uniqueness and pass result to jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have this problem : I'm checking user email in controller and sending json successfull response if it is already taken and add css styling of input, also I need to prevent submit and add some message.

Here is my checkemail action ( used this article - http://paydrotalks.com/posts/45-standard-json-response-for-rails-and-jquery ):

```
def checkemail
  if !User.where('email = ?', params[:email]).empty?
    format.jsonr do
      render :json => { 
        :status => :ok, 
        :message => "Success!",
      }.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

and in my routes:

```
         checkemail GET    /checkemail(.:format)

          match "/checkemail", to: 'edit_user#checkemail'
```

and my jQuery:

```
   $('#user_email').focusout(function() {
    $.getJSON('/checkemail', { email: $('#user_email').val() }, function(data) {
        $('#user_email').addClass("error");
      });
   });
```

my HTML input code:

```
     <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email" value="">
```

from mime_type initializers file:

```
    Mime::Type.register_alias "application/json", :jsonr, %w( text/x-json )
```

**From Fiddler:**

```
  Request : GET /checkemail?user@mail.com HTTP/2.0

  Response(RAW tab) : 
  Missing template edit_user/checkemail

  JSON tab is empty
```

**QUESTIONS: How to inspect is json request sent ? How can I prevent submission form and add some message ?**

Comment: unrelated but use `unless` instead of `if !(something)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
$('#element').focusout(function() {
  $.getJSON('PATH_TO_EMAIL_CHECK_ACTION', { email: $('#element').val() }, function(data) {
    // The data should tell you if its unique or not, you do something
    // here depending on response 
  });
});
```

And in the controller, check if the email is taken. If its not, send back render json with status OK and message success. You can check if the status is success in your callback where the comment is above.

jquery focusout - http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

jquery getJSON - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

About json responses in controller - http://paydrotalks.com/posts/45-standard-json-response-for-rails-and-jquery

Comment: I tried you approach, but failing to implement. Can you look at my code ?

Comment: Please, look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382680/how-to-send-json-response-from-controller-to-jquery-and-inspect-it

Comment: Hmm. In checkemail try doing a flash message and then refresh the page to see it. To disable/enable submit button - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237896/how-to-disable-submit-button-with-jquery

Comment: I'm implemeting it on modal, or you suggest it for testing ?

Comment: Oh also you can log your data in the callback to getJSON. Or just alert it.

Comment: I can alert it using `alert($.getJSON)` or how ?

Comment: `$.getJSON('/checkemail', { email: $('#user_email').val() }, function(data) {
        alert( data );
      });`

Comment: No alert box. It seems to be not executing.

Comment: try just rendering the json no matter what for checkemail and see if it receives something

Comment: When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkemail.jsonr` shows me `{"status":"ok","message":"Success!"}`