# How to send json response from controller to jQuery and inspect it?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, response

I have this problem : I'm checking user email in controller and sending json successfull response if it is already taken and add css styling of input, also I need to prevent submit and add some message.

Here is my checkemail action ( used this article - http://paydrotalks.com/posts/45-standard-json-response-for-rails-and-jquery ):

```
def checkemail
  if !User.where('email = ?', params[:email]).empty?
    format.jsonr do
      render :json => { 
        :status => :ok, 
        :message => "Success!",
      }.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

and in my routes:

```
         checkemail GET    /checkemail(.:format)

          match "/checkemail", to: 'edit_user#checkemail'
```

and my jQuery:

```
   $('#user_email').focusout(function() {
    $.getJSON('/checkemail', { email: $('#user_email').val() }, function(data) {
        $('#user_email').addClass("error");
      });
   });
```

my HTML input code:

```
     <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email" value="">
```

from mime_type initializers file:

```
    Mime::Type.register_alias "application/json", :jsonr, %w( text/x-json )
```

**From Fiddler:**

```
  Request : GET /checkemail?user@mail.com HTTP/2.0

  Response(RAW tab) : 
  Missing template edit_user/checkemail

  JSON tab is empty
```

**QUESTIONS: How to inspect is json request sent ? How can I prevent submission form and add some message ?**

Comment: @KyorCode, I'm not very good at it. How I can add ruby action there ?

Comment: I assume you are running on a localhost, use the "composer" to target your address and change your headers, actiontype ( GET, POST, PUT ) and body of your message accordingly, there are enough examples out there. In your i think case: http://localhost/checkemail

Comment: @KyorCode, do you mean Fiddler or jsfiddler ? I never used fiddler before.

Comment: Fiddler, time to experiment with it.. very handy to debug webservice endpoint functionality

Comment: @KyorCode, are the videos on their ste are useful or it is better to find examples ?

Comment: Those are more aimed at debugging in and outgoing traffic, you want to debug internal "traffic". Try to follow my instruction in my 2nd comment.

Comment: I tried to execute http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkemail . Also tried http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkemail?user@mail.com (email which exists)- result is 404 code.

Comment: `<h1>Unknown action</h1>
<p>The action 'checkemail' could not be found for Devise::RegistrationsController</p>

` from response in RAW tab

Comment: @KyorCode, is it means that I implemented action wrongly ?

Comment: did you enter your method when calling that last url? put a breakpoint in it. If you don't get there, then something else is wrong...

Comment: @KyorCode, checkout my routes - it seems that I entered action correctly.

Comment: @KyorCode , I changed my routes and now response tells me, that template is missing.

Comment: I have to disappoint you there, my Ruby knowledge is not that present...

Comment: I see you are getting there, just baby steps and you'll find your way out of it :)

Comment: @KyorCode, thanks for encouraging me )

Answer (score 0):

Why `format.jsonr` ? Seems like a typo to me.

Comment: I took it from here - http://paydrotalks.com/posts/45-standard-json-response-for-rails-and-jquery

Comment: Did you follow the blog post entirely, or use the gem? Because `jsonr`  (or `jsm` if you're using the gem) is not standard to rails, you have to add support for it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ksol, I added MimeType into initializers file. Is it not enough ?

Comment: @Marijn: if it was a typo, it could have been the answer. @MID: you need to restart your server if you changed/added/deleted an initializer. Otherwise, I'd suggest using `debugger` or `pry` in your action, in order to inspect the params.

Comment: hmmm, ok I see your point, but I still think a comment is more appropriate here. No need to argue though, hopefully this answer will help OP.

Comment: @ksol, I restarted the server and getting the same result - can't send json response.