# How to send simple json response in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I need to send json response depends on user entered data in input, but I'm failing to send simple json request.

I followed this article - http://paydrotalks.com/posts/45-standard-json-response-for-rails-and-jquery .

Added MimeType:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "application/json", :jsonr, %w( text/x-json )
```

and in my controller:

```
 def checkname
  respond_to do |format|
    format.jsonr do
      render :json => { 
         :status => :ok, 
         :message => "Success!",
         :html => "<b>congrats</b>"
      }.to_json
     end  
  end
end
```

but the screen is empty and here is response code from fiddler2 when I composed GET response to this action:

```
    HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
   Cache-Control: no-cache
   X-Request-Id: 14a8467908d9ce322d054607efdacf92
   X-Runtime: 0.011000
   Content-Length: 1
   Connection: keep-alive
  Server: thin 1.4.1 codename Chromeo
```

**What I'm doing wrong ?**

Comment: Are you sure you restarted your app after edition of mime_types.rb? And make sure you're accessing your action via url with `.jsonr` at the end, like: `http://localhost:3000/checkname.jsonr`.

Comment: @jdoe, yeah. you are right. Can you look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382680/how-to-send-json-response-from-controller-to-jquery-and-inspect-it - this is why I need to send json requests.

Comment: Where exactly I am right? :) Did you solve the  problem or it still exists? I tried your code and pointing my browser to `http://localhost:3000/checkname.jsonr` gives me JSON response (application/json).

Comment: Yeah, it is worked for me. Adding `.jsonr`. Can you look at link to question, that posted above ?

Comment: I took a look at those thread. Looks like you want your action to trigger your `format.jsonr` block by default (if you're requesting simply `/checkname`). Am I right?

Comment: @jdoe, yeah I want to check if the email is already taken. Also tried to `$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkemail.jsonr'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16592/discussion-between-jdoe-and-mid)

Answer (score 38):

Not sure about dealing with custom MIME, but as for rendering JSON, this should work:

```
def testme
  respond_to do |format|
    msg = { :status => "ok", :message => "Success!", :html => "<b>...</b>" }
    format.json  { render :json => msg } # don't do msg.to_json
  end
end
```

Also it might help if you state which version of Ruby and Rails you are using.

Comment: i don't know why, but your code is not working for me. My version is working `render :json => { 
      :status => :ok, 
      :message => "Success!",
      :html => "...insert html..."
    }`

Comment: @MID do you include `respond_to :html, :json` at the top of your controller?

Answer (score 25):

I usually use this method to return json data:

```
msg = {:token => token, :courseId => courseId}
render :json => msg
```

Comment: this is quite simple!

Answer (score 9):

One Simple way is:

```
def my_action 

 render :json => {:name => "any name"}

end
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is `render json: {foo: 'bar'}`