# Why is my ajax call failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I set up an ajax call and it keeps going to the fail function and not the done one. It keeps console logging "doesn't work" instead of "works". My code is as follows. The url '/' is the index method.

```
var data = 
    {
        "latlng": [e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType : "json",
        data: data
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log("didnt work");
    })
```

my controller

```
def index

if request.xhr?
   return "works!"
end
```

end
I know it hits the request.xhr because I put a binding.pry there and I see my data, but it doesnt seem to return "works!".

EDIT: I got it working per the comments below. I get a response now, but its an html response. I returned the string "works" but it doesnt seem to appear as my ajax response.

Comment: never output fixed "it didn't work" messages. They're USELESS for debugging. `.fail(function(e) { console.log(e); }`

Comment: @MarcB oh, I didn't realize that. Thank you so much for the tip!

Comment: You are not returning json...just a string. By default it will be treated as html. In your controller specify the rendered output type. The first answer in this question should give you a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385345/how-to-send-simple-json-response-in-rails

Comment: If you want it in actual plain text, see http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render and look for the red text "Rendering Text".

Answer (score 4):

If you look in the web console, you'll probably see an error. You've told jQuery that it should expect JSON back, but what you're sending back isn't valid JSON, so when jQuery tries to parse it, it fails.

If you remove `dataType: "json"` or return valid JSON from the controller, it should work.

Comment: thank you so much T.J.! I initially thought dataType was the structure in which my data should be sent and not what i should receive back. I get a response now, but its an html response. I returned the string "works" but it doesnt seem to appear as my ajax response.

Comment: @bwuuu: *"I initially thought dataType was the structure in which my data should be sent and not what i should receive back."* Yeah, you're not the first or only one to make that mistake, the naming could be a lot better on the `ajax` options. :-) (The option for the format of `data` is `contentType`.)

Comment: @bwuuu: *"I get a response now, but its an html response. I returned the string "works" but it doesnt seem to appear as my ajax response."* I'm not following what you mean by "html response" vs. "ajax response". (The response to an ajax request can be HTML, that's not a problem.)

Comment: Sorry, I should've have been more clear. In this portion of my code[.done(function(response){console.log(response);]  i want the response to be "works" because that is what i returned in my controller. However the response I get is the index.html.erb page.

Comment: @bwuuu: Ah. Sorry, I can't help you with that part, Ruby isn't my thing. I spotted the jQuery issue and figured I could answer that, didn't realize the Ruby side also had a separate issue.