# Ruby send Json response to http post call

Tags: json, ruby, rest, sinatra

I currently have Ruby code that takes a http post from the client.  It makes another http post, and I want to send a json response based on the response from the post.  How do I do this?  I am trying to use the answer from this post:  [How to send simple json response in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385345/how-to-send-simple-json-response-in-rails)

But it is giving me errors when I try to compile.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rest-client'
require 'sequel'
require 'pg'
require 'json/ext'

require 'net/http'
require 'json'

require 'monza'
require 'time'

post '/receiptValidation' do
  # Find devices with the corresponding reg_tokens
  base64ReceiptDataString = params[:base64ReceiptDataString]


  uri = URI("https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com") 
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 
    'https') do |http|
      response = http.post('/verifyReceipt', params_json)
      parsedJson = JSON.parse(response.body)

      # ***** send JSON response here *******
      respond_to do |format|
      # ... other formats here ...
        format.jsonr do
          render :json => { 
            :status => :ok, 
            :message => "Success!",
            :html => "...insert html..."
          }.to_json
        end        
      end
  end
end
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
2017-08-20 02:36:04 - NoMethodError - undefined method `respond_to' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x007f0dcb04ba70>
2017-08-20T02:36:04.949145+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean?  respond_to?:
2017-08-20T02:36:04.949146+00:00 app[web.1]:    firebasepushserver.rb:315:in `block in <main>'
```

I want to get the response in the following swift code:

```
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            print("done")
        }
        task.resume()
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: 2017-08-20 02:36:04 - NoMethodError - undefined method `respond_to' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x007f0dcb04ba70>
2017-08-20T02:36:04.949145+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean?  respond_to?:
2017-08-20T02:36:04.949146+00:00 app[web.1]:  firebasepushserver.rb:315:in `block in <main>'

Comment: It seems your app is a Sinatra application rather than rails. Consider edit the tag and removes ruby-on-rails tag in the question.

Comment: yes, it is a sinatra application.  I didn't know that was different from rails.  so I need to find how to do it with sinatra?

Comment: They are different  web framework although the are both written in Ruby.

Comment: is it possible to do it in sinatra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change

```
respond_to do |format|
  # ... other formats here ...
  format.jsonr do
    render :json => {
        :status => :ok,
        :message => "Success!",
        :html => "...insert html..."
    }.to_json
  end
end
```

to

```
  content_type :json
  {
      :status => :ok,
      :message => "Success!",
      :html => "...insert html..."
  }.to_json
```

It uses `content_type`, you can find the doc [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sinatra/sinatra/Sinatra%2FHelpers%3Acontent_type).

Comment: I tried replacing the code block with the one you gave, but the response is blank.  the docs say that this code fills the response, but what is the command to actually send the response?

Comment: @mjpablo23 This code will definitely work as long as you add the code in the `post` block of sinatra.  Because I test it in my computer.

Comment: ah i see.  I have it in the post block.  I keep getting this as a response in swift:  response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170237020> { URL: http://appname.herokuapp.com/receiptvalidation } { status code: 404, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";

Comment: this is what it prints on heroku:  [20/Aug/2017:05:29:27 +0000] "POST /receiptvalidation HTTP/1.1" 404 18 0.0024

Comment: oh I fixed the 404 problem.  but the response is still blank right now.

Comment: ah it is working now.  I had a problem with the url that I was posting to.  thanks a lot!  I've been stuck on this for a long time.  do you recommend me switching to node.js?  I feel like the sinatra documentation is not that good.

Comment: @mjpablo23 Do you have much experience in JavaScript? If you have more experience in JavaScript than Ruby, you may try to switch. I don't think sinatra documentation is bad, but definitely there are more javascript resources on the Internet.

Comment: ah I see, no I don't know javascript actually.  I've just been hearing a lot about node.js, so it seems like a more modern language.  is that true?