# How to convert Mongod collection to JSON - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I want to get data form my react component from mongodb on rails . I need to convert data to json so my react component can read it . I try some code but it not work . Anyone have any ideas how to do this ? . Thank a lot

```
def home
    pricedata = Mongoid::Clients.default
    data = pricedata[:coin_prices]
    coin_prices = JSON.parse(data) #not work
    puts data
  end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385345/how-to-send-simple-json-response-in-rails

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVE : just .to_a is ok , the output is json format

```
def home
        pricedata = Mongoid::Clients.default
        @data = pricedata[:coin_prices].to_a # @data is ok to use by react
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the job :

```
def home
  pricedata = Mongoid::Clients.default
  data = pricedata[:coin_prices]
  render json: data
end
```

Comment: Stack level too deep bro :(