# Require the email to be unique with Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using the Simple Form gem, how can I only allow a user to submit the form only if their email has not yet been used to submit a form.

Comment: Add some code to your question. What have you tried?

Comment: I found this code online ´validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }´ but I don't know where to put it. I tried to put it in the post controller and on the actual form. But it didn't work.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328873/how-to-check-user-email-uniqueness-and-pass-result-to-jquery

Comment: It must be possible without jQuery?

Comment: @FCD In your User model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it in your **model** which has an *email* field, and **not** in your **controller**, add the following code

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true
```

what does this code do?

This will prevent users to use email id which are already present in your database. don't forget to check right if I'm correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Venom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54981868/10608621), I recommend using unique index.

Because there may be a situation when there will be requests with the same email at the same time. And they will be validated. In this case, you will have duplicates.

For this purpose make constraints. It will be something like

```
$ rails g migration AddIndexToObjects


class AddIndexToObjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :objects, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, this constraint should be used for email, but he was confused in where and how to use validates :email, uniqueness: true.

Comment: Have you read the question? 'get posted if the email has not been used in a post before. How can I do this?'

Comment: Oh yes, But I took the question regarding validations