# disable submit button using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to disable submit button in my form once it s clicked to restrict user to click it again and again i tried this with jquery

```
$('form').submit(function()
{  
    var formId = this.id;
    if (formId != ''){
        $('#'+formId+' :input[type=submit]').attr('disabled',true);
        this.submit();
    }
});
```

my problem s that i have two submit button s in my page which i m checking in controller to direct but i m not getting any post values once i disable the submit button in my form.
Is there any other way to prevent user to restrict multiple clicks ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to disable submit button with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237896/how-to-disable-submit-button-with-jquery)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have an id or a name for  the `submit` button. Disable that button only

For example:

HTML

```
<form id="frm_name">
     <input type="submit" id="btn_submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery

```
...
if (formId != ''){
    $('#btn_submit').attr('disabled',true);
    this.submit();
}
...
```

Comment: s this will solve my problem as this s the commonfunction which i want to call all over my app i can call this function in onsubmit of each button with formid and disable field parmeter

Answer (score 3):

In my case `$('#btn_submit').prop("disabled", true);` worked!

**Update:**

I was using kendo grid inside some specific rows I want to disable `Edit` and `Delete` inline buttons. I tried many alternate ways to disable it but **.prop()** worked like charm!

Comment: This is in the low quality posts queue. I'm voting it looks okay, but you should add some more information about why this works when the OP's attempts didn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can also disable the event like this,

```
$('form').submit(function(e)
{ 

e.preventDefault();
//then carry out another way of submitting the content.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#submit_button_1').prop('disabled', true);
$('#submit_button_2').prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="submit_button_1" value="Submit" />
<button type="submit" id="submit_button_2">Submit</button>
```