# How to perform div disable in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div (a button) to which i need apply disable property when I hover mouse there.

```
<div class="button">click me</button>
```

It works fine when i do like below,

```
 <div id="button" disabled>click me</button>
```

But i need to apply conditionally in my js,

```
 $("#button").css("disbale");
```

Can anyone please help me.Thanks.
    But i want to disable it only on mouse hower.

Comment: Try $("#button").prop("disabled", true);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery disable/enable submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable submit button using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194926/disable-submit-button-using-jquery)

Comment: You are attempting to disable the `div` which is not possible, seems you want all elements in div to be disabled. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555295/how-to-disable-div-element-and-everything-inside)

Comment: [You mean like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/o5bh4np3/12/)

Comment: just curious, you have a tag `angularjs` in your Qstn,  so if you're using angular1.x then it can achieved by `ng-disabled` directive, and you shouldn't be using jquery. If not then please remove the tag.:)

Answer (score 1):

Use prop

`$("#button").prop("disabled",true);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('div').hover(function(){
             $("#button").prop("disabled", true);
        });
```

Comment: For better you could add  what is  `pop()`?  with some reference link  .its more helpful for `OP` and also  easily to attract the up voter

Answer (score 1):

The mouse event will not get fired on the disabled field in case you want use mouseout function.

```js
$("button").hover(function(){
    $(this).prop("disabled", true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button>Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do the following:**

```
$("#button").disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use from this code:

```
  $('button').mouseover(function() {
    $('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
```

you can check this:https://jsfiddle.net/MortezaFathnia/o28hmdq8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this : 
Using `JavaScript`

```
document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
```

Using `JQuery`:

```
$("#button").prop("disabled",true);
```