# disable the submit button if the username already exist using ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, submit

I am having a code that will check if the username is available in the database, the code can show an error message that the email is already exists but when I press the submit button it will insert the username in the database even if the username is already exists.

here is my code:

```
function validateForm(){
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Name").change(function () {
        var username = $("#Name").val();
        var msg = $("#msg");
        if (username.length > 2) {
            $("#msg").html('Checking availability');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "check_availability.php",
                data: "Name=" + username,
                success: function (messagess) {
                    $("#msg").ajaxComplete(function (event, request) {
                        if (messagess.indexOf('OK') > 0) {
                            $("#Name").removeClass("exists");
                            $("#Name").addClass("avail");
                            msg.html('the user name is available</font>');
                        } else {
                            $("#Name").removeClass("avail");
                            $("#Name").addClass("exists");
                            msg.html('the user name is already exists');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" name="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">    
User Email:&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="" />
<span id="msg"></span>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Always check server side as well. Even if JavaScript validation is used, it is trivially easy to bypass that. On the server side send an error if there user-name is already in use. Never just rely on data from the client as being validated already.

Comment: Also, please use our search feature. See [how to disable submit button with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1237896/911182)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll wanna use `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` on the the element you want to disable, if the check returns that the username already exists. And to remove the disabling you'll use `.removeAttr('disabled')`.

And just a recommendation, if you havn't already throw in a fallback php validation check that way if javascript is disabled there is still validation in place.